# Maximum and minimum values of $y=\frac{ax^2+2bx+c}{Ax^2+2Bx+C}$

Tags: functions

Prove that the maximum and minimum values of $y=\frac{ax^2+2bx+c}{Ax^2+2Bx+C}$ are those for which $({ax^2+2bx+c})-y({Ax^2+2Bx+C})$ is a perfect square.

I tried to solve this problem using the value of $y'=0$.

Solving the I got $y=\frac{ax+b}{Ax+B}$.

Now I need to prove that $T=({ax^2+2bx+c})-y({Ax^2+2Bx+C})$ is a perfect square by substituting the value of $y=\frac{ax+b}{Ax+B}$ but failed.

Comment: For a non-calculus approach, I suspect the method illustrated [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6528441) can be used. Indeed, you can probably find this in the 1800s literature I allude to (I gave one specific reference).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By the quotient rule we get
$$y'=-2\,{\frac {Ab{x}^{2}-Ba{x}^{2}+Acx-Cax+Bc-Cb}{ \left( A{x}^{2}+2\,Bx+
C \right) ^{2}}}
$$